# Do myFunction right after JSONP request

Tags: jquery, html, autocomplete, jsonp

I have a script which allows to display Google suggestions: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/24mD8/9/)

I want to do a function with the first li item rendered by the ui autocomplete, so I did this:

```
$("input#term").keyup(function() {
    DoMyFunction($('.ui-autocomplete li:first-child a').text(), true);
});
```

The problem however is that there is a period of time between the keyup---> request--->xml cache and html rendering by the ui autocomplete. Which means the my function (DoMyFunction) is being triggered when there is no html list, hence it doesnt work. So my question is: How do I do my function right after the reqeust is cached and processed. Setting a timer wont work because there are to many variables to account for (ea user bandwidth).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [jQuery UI docs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#event-open), there's an `open` event which is triggered when the suggestion menu is opened

You'll have to do something like this :

```
$("#term").autocomplete({

  source: function( request, response ) {
    // ajax function
  },
    select: function(e, ui){
        //
    }
   open : function(){
        //here you are sure the suggestion menu is opened
        DoMyFunction($('.ui-autocomplete li:first-child a').text(), true);
   }
 });
```

Comment: Thanks, I have to try this later on, but for now I give credit because it is definitely useful answer